# Can you put MySql database and JSP pages on Arduino

Tags: jsp, arduino

Is it posible to put MySql database on Arduino ? And is it posible to put JSP pages on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino is a microcontroller that is powered by microprocessors from the comapny Atmel's Atmega series. It is a very small computer with very less memories. Essentially Arduino has total memory in the range of 32kb and RAM in the range of 1kb or 2kb depending on the model. It is used for hardware projects. Why would you want to store Mysql database and JSP pages on it. These are part of web applications and Arduino is not right for web applications. Microcontrollers like Arduino are used for hardware related or embedded systems projects.

To work on a web app you will obviously be working on a pc. Now if you want to control the Arduino via another device (in your case a pc) that device needs to be continuously connected to Arduino. So assuming that the Arduino is connected through the USB port to the pc what you could do is have a serial connection maintained and you can use that connection in your web app (which would be running on a traditional server or localhost on your pc) to send or receive data through Arduino. If you plan to connect Arduino via bluetooth or other wireless protocols you can use that connection instead of a serial one too.

Comment: But if i want to control arduino via my web application that uses database, and is made of JSP pages can I do it. Maybe put micro SD card and store data to it?

Comment: You can but maybe you also should look at beaglebone black, raspberry pi or, if you want an arduino emulator an Intel Galileo. These all have the ability to server websites or to act similar to arduino using digital and analog IO. The Intel Galileo has an arduino emulator